# Apple mach-0 linker error NSInteger

Tags: objective-c

I am getting the following error(and YES, I have already search through google again and again):

[image]

I have multiple 'extern NSInteger' defined and can use them, though this 'timeofclick' for some reason causes this error

On other threads people talk about adding frameworks and including stuff, but here I'm just using one more NSInteger

In my .h

[image]

In my .m

[image]

Comment: The images you've posted are identical for both .h and .m. Looks like they're both the header. Can you post the .m file?

Comment: @Ben, now I corrected that.
What bothers me most is that I know declaring them as properties might not be correct/optimal, but this exact way of doing things har worked for me in several other projects. Then suddenly this shows up and same thing happens for me in a new project I created just for testing this. That's whats making me thing some setting might have been changed in my Xcode program

Comment: @user3649561 do you use same variable name in different classes ?

Comment: I'm using the same variable in different functions. But these variable names are only use in this one .m file
Sorry in advance, but I've never really gotten hold of when there's talk of a class and when it's something else
@QueueOverFlow

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you haven't actually *defined* the `timeOfClick` variable anywhere (inside a .m file). Putting the extern declaration in a header says "don't worry, this thing will get defined somewhere, and you'll find it at link time". If the linker comes along (like here) and it can't actually find the variable defined, you'll get an error like this.

Essentially you want to have an `NSInteger timeOfClick` somewhere in an implementation (.m) file.

Comment: I have all of my further code coming in after the viewDidLoad, and first thing in viewDidLoad is    timeofclick = 10;

Comment: In particular what I just can not understand is why this ONE variable is troubling me while all the others work fine

Comment: @user3649561 Do you have, at the top of the .m file anywhere, outside of any method, a line that just says `NSInteger timeOfClick;`?

Comment: I have included it as a property, if that's what you mean?

Comment: @user3649561: When you say you have "extern NSInteger timeOfClick;" declared somewhere (usually in a .h file), that's a global variable, not an ObjC property. It must have a corresponding "NSInteger timeOfClick;" definition inside of a .m file, not part of your class.

Comment: all of my integers are 'defined' in the .h as: 
extern NSInteger myvariable;

and then in the .m they are all referred to as 

@property NSInteger myvariable;

I have done so a lot of times, and everywhere else this is working

Comment: @user3649561: Extern declarations are not intended to be paired with properties. I'm not sure what this pattern is accomplishing for you. You may wish to post your full .h and .m files in the question, or at least all of the relevant pieces.

Comment: Now I uploaded with my definitions of the variables

Comment: I'm starting to think if there's something fundamentally broken with my .h and/or .m file(s). Right now I tried setting all of my code as either comments or with breakpoints in the code - so that it only runs the viewDidload and implements the other variables. And it's still coming up with the same error about a variable that's not even in use now

Comment: Now I went as far as starting a new project an trying multiple times to just define a few variables by copying the exact same definitions that I have used in previous projects - still getting the mach-o linker error. 
Could there be some change to my entire Xcode program??

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the error because you didn't write

```
@synthesize timeofclick2;
```

under your `@implementation ReactingViewController`.

By default, the compiler will generate an instance variable (ivar) for you if you only declare a property but you don't synthesize it explicitly. The generated ivar usually goes by `_<property_name>`, like in your case `_timeofclick2`, instead of the same name as the property.

Thus, you got the error when you tried to call `timeofclick2` without `_` prefix because there is no ivar with that name.

By explicitly write `@synthesize <property_name>` (without '<..>'), the compiler will generate ivar for you with the exact name of the property.

So, if you add the code I mentioned above, the compiler will create ivar `timeofclick2` for you. Then you can access it via your extern.

...Or another solution, you can just change the extern from

```
extern NSInteger timeofclick2;
```

to

```
extern NSInteger _timeofclick2;
```

Then you'd be fine :D

Comment: I have now tried synthesizing all my properties. Somehow this has made a difference! Now I have only one error left which is a 'Duplicate Symbol Error for architecture i386', for which I'm now searching around. Thanks so far!

Comment: I think the only problem now is that I have two sets of .h and .m files that are doing the same, just for testing - and therefore I have one or more dublicate methods(by the same name). Is it possible to deactivate .m and .h files so that they won't interfere?

Comment: If you don't use them, so you can remove them from your project setting in the `Build Phases > Compile Sources`. Or you can remove those files from your project.